# Is it possible to auto-generate custom HTTP Headers using nswag (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, swagger-codegen, nswag

I use `nswag` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nswag) to generate http services, interfaces, etc.

The typescript code for a typical service proxy looks as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class TenantsServiceProxy {
...
    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
    ...

    getTenantId(subdomain: string | null): Observable<number | null> {
    ...
        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json"
                })
            };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).flatMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processGetTenantId(response_);
        }).catch((response_: any) => {
        ...
```

Regarding the bit where `HTTP Headers` are detailed:

I wonder if there's a way to tell the `nswag` tool to add an extra header (`Authorization` for JWT Bearer in my case) automatically?

Of course there's sort of a hacky workaround to replace the headers bit using text editor with the following code:

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        })
```

But I suspect there might be a way to include additional headers.

Maybe someone has already solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable UseTransformOptionsMethod, set a ClientBaseClass and define the method in the base class with extension code...

See https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/SwaggerToTypeScriptClientGenerator#transform-the-options-or-the-result

Comment: The link above doesn’t work anymore. New link: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator#transform-the-options-or-the-result

Comment: options.headers.append("myheader", "myvalue");  did not work for me in Angular. I had to change it to options.headers = options.headers.append("myheader", "myvalue");  because HttpHeaders is immutable, but appending and reassigning does the trick